# nuget package add folder to solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

i have to create a nuget package but i have a problem: i want to add a folder named "Config", this folder contains three XML files.

after a search on the web, i have tried two ways (editing my nuspec file) to add this custom folder into my nuget package:

1)

```
<file src="Config\*.*" target="content\Config" />
```

2)

```
<file src="Config\*.*" target="Config" />
```

... but no one of these seem to work!

I have tried to add this package on a Test's solution (Console application), the dll was attached to the solution but "Config" folder doesn't appeared on the root of the solution.

What is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Lollo

**EDIT**

[nuget spec and project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOpA8.png)

[nuget spec opened into nuget package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxhM1.png)

My Nuget Specification file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>    
        <id>Onions.Framework.Core</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <title>Onions Framework Core</title>
        <authors>Onions Corporate</authors>
        <owners>Onions Corporate</owners>
        <licenseUrl>http://url/framework/core/license.txt</licenseUrl>
        <projectUrl>http://url/framework/core/</projectUrl>
        <iconUrl>http://url/framework/icon.png</iconUrl>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>no description</description>
        <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Onions Corporate</copyright>
        <tags></tags>
        <dependencies>
              <dependency id="Castle.Core" version="4.2.1" />
              <dependency id="Castle.Windsor" version="4.1.0" />
              <dependency id="CommonServiceLocator" version="2.0.1" />
              <dependency id="FluentNHibernate" version="2.0.3" />
              <dependency id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.3" />
              <dependency id="log4net" version="2.0.8" />
              <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
              <dependency id="NHibernate" version="4.1.1.4000" />
        </dependencies>
        <summary></summary>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\*.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
        <file src="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\*.pdb" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />

        <file src="Config\*.*" target="content\Config" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Do you want to add the folder to the `solution`, or to the `project` in the solution that you added the nuget reference to?

Comment: right question! i would mean "project" instead "solution"! my fault :/

Comment: you can edit your question to reflect that nuance

Comment: @Lollo, How about this issue now? Have you check my updated answer? If it not help, please let me know for free.

Comment: @leoLiu-MSFT, sorry i had no-time to check your update, in these next 2 days i try your answer... very sorry... thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the problem? Thanks in advance!

The "Config" folder should appeared on the root of the **project** rather than solution.

That because NuGet team [deprecated solution level packages](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522) in NuGet 3.0.

So the content files comes from nuget package should be added to the project, not the solution.

Besides, according the [From a convention-based working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package):

[image]

The convention-based working directory `content`, **Contents are copied to the project root**.

The "Config" folder should appeared on the root of the project.

[image]

**Update:**

> i have edited my question with your requests :) i'm using .NET core 2.0

Since you test project type is .net core. You should use `contentFiles` instead of `content`. `content` is used for packages.config. Check the [Using the contentFiles element for content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files) and blog [NuGet ContentFiles Demystified](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) for more details.

So your `.nuspec` file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Onions.Framework.Core</id>
    ...

    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Config/*.*" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="false" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>

  </metadata>

  <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\*.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
        <file src="bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\*.pdb" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
        <file src="contentFiles\any\any\Config\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any\Config" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The nuget package should be looks like:

[image]

**Note:** When you create a new package, do not forgot to remove the nuget cache for this package in the `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages` folder, otherwise, it always install the old package.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, i would mean "project" instead "solution".
but i cannot import the "Config" folder to my project using nuget :( even if the dll and pdb files are imported successfully...

Comment: @Lollo, so you means your "Config" folder doesn't appeared on the root of the project? If yes, could you please share your .nuspec file to me or your nuget package to me, if you do not mind. And what is your project type of your Console application, .net framework or .net core?

Comment: i have edited my question with your requests :)

i'm using .NET core 2.0

Comment: @Lollo, Since you test project type is .net core. You should use `contentFiles` instead of `content`. `content` is used for packages.config. Check my update answer for details.

Comment: @Lollo, I have uploaded the error `.nuspec` file, please change it to`<file src="contentFiles\any\any\Config\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any\Config" />`, I have updated the answer, you can check it. I have test it with a .net core app.

Comment: Why `any/any/...` ?