# Generate text file of public API of .NET library for versioning and compatibility tracking

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I maintain far too many NuGet packages and I'm trying to find a tool that generates a plain text file of the public API surface for each assembly (like a post-build step). Each namespace, class, interface, struct, method signature, member, field, would be a line, all alphabetically sorted.

Having a `src/PublicAPIs.txt` file change whenever I change the public API surface would be amazing - the github diff would immediately show me what I modified or removed or added, and the file would be invaluable for tracking API changes over time.

I'd be far less likely to accidentally expose a private API or break an existing one, I think.

I feel like this must already exist and I'm just missing something? I know of Telerik JustAssembly for basic .dll comparisons, but I'm looking for something than can write a file to the git repository automatically so I don't have to remember to open a tool, and any breaking change will pop up during my normal workflow.

Comment: Don’t you use xml comments? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags
It can produce xml on every build.

Comment: I suppose the XML could be transformed into something concise enough to be useful for this... but reflection might be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a couple tools that could work out here: `Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers`.

### Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers

Including a package reference for [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/PublicApiAnalyzers/PublicApiAnalyzers.Help.md) will result in generation of text files that make it easy to identify breaking changes in your APIs.

OpenTelemetry has an example of using [different text files for different target frameworks](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/ee11de90a37915c68d9d44cdd283ba6047b394a3/build/Common.prod.props#L78)

### Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat

[ApiCompat](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat/README.md) can also be used to test API compatibility between a two .NET assemblies.

Unfortunately, [this project is not on nuget.org](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/issues/6070) yet, but it is used outside of a variety of Microsoft projects by *at least* [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.csproj#L47) and [OpenTelemetry](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/ee11de90a37915c68d9d44cdd283ba6047b394a3/build/Common.prod.props#L14).

Here's a [blog post](https://stu.dev/check-for-breaking-changes-with-apicompat/) that does a nice walkthrough of adding the package, which I'll just briefly summarize without trying to duplicate too much of the content:

1. Add [.NET Core Tools nuget feed](https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/index.json) to your nuget.config
2. Add a package reference for "Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat"
3. Add a reference to a copy of the previous major version of the assembly (or [use a script](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/build/PreBuild.ps1) to get it)

The default setup should result in a broken build when you make breaking changes, but you can change this behavior through the [additional settings](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat/README.md#additional-settings) like `BaselineAllAPICompatError` that are available, [as Automapper has](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.csproj#L26-L27)

Comment: This is a really interesting tool. For my use case I think a text file would be better. I do make breaking changes - I just need awareness of them and an easy way to see it all at a glance in git history.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/API-Changes.html

Comment: @LilithRiver sorry, I saw ApiCompat and thought it also did the text files and I was maybe just missing something... updated the answer to recommend `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers` as that seems to be exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @Tim That's exactly how AM works with ApiCompat.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu for calling that out, you're absolutely right. I've updated the answer to indicate the specific property that changes that behavior. At this point I think either tool should work.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the [PublicApiGenerator](https://github.com/PublicApiGenerator/PublicApiGenerator) NuGet package for that.

It provides a very simple way to generate a `string` that contains your Public API from one or more assemblies.

The following sample (taken from the project's README) shows how you can use the package to create a unit test that will fail when the public API has changed:

```cs
[Fact]
public void my_assembly_has_no_public_api_changes()
{
    var publicApi = typeof(Library).Assembly.GeneratePublicApi();

    var approvedFilePath = "PublicApi.approved.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(approvedFilePath))
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        using (var sw = File.CreateText(approvedFilePath)) { }
    }

    var approvedApi = File.ReadAllText(approvedFilePath);

    Assert.Equal(approvedApi, publicApi);
}
```

The test above will force you to regenerate a the approved API on breaking changes, so that breaking changes will be a concious decision.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you just want to check if API has breaking changes and warn about if it has. I would recommend to use swagger for your API's so it's easy to explore the API's. But it can also be used to check / test for breaking changes:

https://swagger.io/blog/api-development/using-swagger-to-detect-breaking-api-changes/

eg:

```
$ gem install swagger-diff
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-minimal.json

$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json

$ swagger-diff petstore-minimal.json petstore-expanded.json
```

So you would just need to save the swagger file on build

eg: https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-generate-a-swagger-json-file-on-build-in-net-core-fa74eec3df1

If your not already using swagger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Hope this helps :)

Comment: We're talking about .NET classes, interfaces, and members, not web api surfaces. I don't think swagger does .dll interfaces?

Comment: @LilithRiver > Your right :D Sorry missunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy these DLL content tracking requirements, you will need to develop a console app that will need to be invoked in post build stepd which will need to contain the following routines:

To read managed DLL you can follow these approaches:
[Assembly.LoadFrom Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_) or [Using Reflection to load unreferenced assemblies at runtime in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a)

To read unmanaged DLLs:
[Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) or [PInvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/)

At the same console app, after read the DLL(s) contents, you can write these content using these approach: [How to write to a text file (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

I think that's all.

Comment: I know how to go about building such a tool; but what I'm looking for is for something that's already been created and optimized.

Answer (score 0):

[ILSpyCmd](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/tree/master/ICSharpCode.ILSpyCmd) is the most close one that I can find which

1. Is a CLI tool for easy post-build integration.
2. Has an option to dump some of the entities you want:

`-l|--list <entity-type(s)>         Lists all entities of the specified type(s). Valid types: c(lass), i(nterface), s(truct), d(elegate), e(num)`

3. Is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilspycmd). However, it is installed via `dotnet tool install -g` which should be a bit different from what you are expecting.

The output looks like this:
[image]

And as you can see it still lacks some detail info such as methods and fields in a class, but all the details (method signatures, enum members, etc) should be already decompiled into the `decompiler` object in `ListContent()` method of `IlspyCmdProgram.cs`. You might clone the repos and then add a few lines to walk it through and print with your preferred format.

Answer (score 0):

this was a very nice question, first let me share some background on the NuGet packages, and baked in capabilities which are broadly divided into three parts: [`common`, `sender` & `receivers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/source), which are readily available for you from various repo providers, see pics below.

> 1. Simple answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849735/6085193) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68835503/6085193), by doing something relatively simple like `<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>` all the text is copied. If you put all the nugets refs in a versioned class library. You will automatically get all the `text & changes` in one click with `MSbuild`. You can diff that to the previous version in the git if you choose.

---

> 2. For something more proactive - I think `Webhooks` are purpose built and hook up to each lib sources, especially since the receivers and custom receivers are already coded as part of nuget in the package specs. If I wasn't between/hunting for work, I would have quickly mocked up something fun :)

> ### I recommend this design as a good fit for 2 reasons, when I did something similar for a free alternative, `1`) since they/`Webhooks` are natively built in, from Nuget Ref -> "*...`Nuget Receivers`: A set of packages supporting receiving WebHooks from others...*"  You can just tap into that data stream, by simply requesting it.

[image: Nuget webhook recievers]

`2`) now, you can process your webhook in the app, or in your lib, or some VSIX repo extension easily.

```
public class MyNugetApiChangesHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public MyNugetApiChangesHandler ()
    {
        // let them know
        this.Receiver = "PublicApisChanged";
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        CustomNotifications notifications = context.GetDataOrDefault<CustomNotifications>();
        foreach (var notification in notifications.Notifications)
        {
            // parse out the text and raise out the handler
            ...
        }
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

> below you can also observe the dll's that allow you subscribe to various repos are *already available* to you.

---

You can do this directly from Github
[image: Github PR repo changes, Git SVN Wehbooks and Recievers Nuget processing]

---

You can do this with [Bitbucket](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Bitbucket/) as well
[image: Bitbucket Git SVN Wehbooks and Recievers Nuget processing]
[image: Webhooks ASP]